# How Do I Get The CPU Percentage For All Threads In The JVM?

Tags: java, linux, sigar

I have a java monitoring application that I use to monitor CPU (amongst other things) on linux.

I am using Sigar to get the CPU usage for my processes.
http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DOUGM/hyperic-sigar-1.6.3-src/docs/javadoc/org/hyperic/sigar/Sigar.html#getProcCpu%28long%29

However, this is just at a process level. htop shows the threads in my application and the CPU percentage that each is using.

Is it possible to do that with Sigar?

If I am on a multi-core box, is it possible to get the CPU utilisation per core?

I'd like to alert when the CPUs are running at 100% for long periods and identify the likely culprits in the thread list.

Comment: you can always used `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(yourcmd);` to execute your command (htop, etc), and then `process.getInputStream();` to read the returned data from the command.

Comment: The difficulty with system monitoring is that they are very OS dependent. Even if it is decided that any jvm implenentation must provide some api, I guess it is difficult to define a common api that works for all OS

Answer (score 0):

JMX can be used to get this information from the Java runtime, although it seems the CPU load is not part of the standard Java API and you need to cast to `com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean`:

```
OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
double loadAverage = osBean.getSystemLoadAverage();
System.out.println("Load average: " + loadAverage);

if (osBean instanceof com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)
{
    com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean sunOsBean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)osBean;
    double cpuLoad = sunOsBean.getSystemCpuLoad();
    System.out.println("CPU load: " + cpuLoad);
}
```

Comment: This is useful, however, as far as I am aware, this is at a process level and not at a thread level.